# Reading a pdf file from GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, request

So, I'm having trouble parsing a PDF file from a GET request, I'm using the pdf2text lib.

I can parse files normally from the file path:

```
var pdfText = require('pdf2Text');
var fs = require('fs');

var buffer = fs.readFileSync('C:/myPdf.pdf');

pdfText(buffer).then(function(result){
    // do some stuff with the result here
})
```

But I'm not sure how to get the buffer from a HTTP request, I tried to do a `new Buffer(response)` but it didn't work (I'm using the request-promise library by the way). Keep in mind that I don't really want to save the file, just read it as buffer.

EDIT: What I'm trying to do:

```
request('http://blabla.com/pdfs/myPdf.pdf').then(function(response){
    var buffer = new Buffer(response);

    pdfText(buffer).then(function(result){
        // doesn't work with this buffer
    })
});
```

I guess this probably isn't doable with the request-promise and I should use the standard request, but still I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Not clear what is being sent in the GET url, or what you want to send or what the whole process flow is supposed to be

Comment: @charlietfl added an edit with what I'm trying to do, not sure if it does make sense tho.

Comment: What is `content`?

Comment: @GBarroso : tell me one thing ... do you want to receive this file from a multipart form or you take the file from a server? However +1 because you help me to find a module to extract pdf text without external dependencies!